# Image on floating menu bar when scrolling page

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu

Im trying to implement the menu bar when scrolling page but the image inside the DIV do not follow the visibility (is always on).

How can I make the image follow the menu bar?

Thanks

Here is the code

SCRIPT:

```
<script>
//STICKY NAV
$(document).ready(function () {  

  $(window).scroll(function (event) {
    // what the y position of the scroll is
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    // whether that's below the form
    if (y >= 30) {
      // if so, ad the fixed class
      $('.logo').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
      // otherwise remove it
      $('.logo').removeClass('fixed'); 
    }
  });
});

</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="logo">
<img src="img/logo001.png" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.logo.fixed {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    background: #000;
    height: 60px;
    pagging-left:8%;    
    z-index:9999;
}
```

Comment: Please provide the whole code or create a jsfiddler for it

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle or codepen link that shows your problem